# Доработать скрипт модального окна, чтобы обрабатывал несколько div

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

JS не знаю совсем, но стоит задача сделать модальные изображения на странице. Нашла скрипт, но он обрабатывает только одно изображение. Как можно его доработать так, чтобы он обрабатывал 4 изображения на странице? (сейчас я написала для каждого изображения по такому скрипту, для каждого создаю переменные, думаю это нерационально). Заранее большое спасибо.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  //    modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */

.modal-img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img id="myImg" src="img/modern.png" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img src="img/modern_modal.jpg" class="modal-content" id="img01">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Нужно объединить все нужные картинки (в моём случае, я всем присвоил атрибут `data-modal`). Далее с помощью цикла присваиваем всем картинкам функции.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Ищу все картинки с атрибутом "data-moda"
var o_imageMOdal = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal]');

// Создаю цикл для всех картинок с атрибутом "data-moda"
for (var i = 0; i < o_imageMOdal.length; i++) {
  var img = o_imageMOdal[i]; // Тут я обращаюсь к картинке из цикла и дальше присваиваю ей все остальные функции
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  };

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */

.modal-img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsJn.jpg?s=500&g=1" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image" data-modal>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTgj1.jpg?s=500&g=1" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image" data-modal>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-UgApXvPkjjo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABI/nXfAsIiva_E/photo.jpg?sz=500" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image" data-modal>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img src="img/modern_modal.jpg" class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Я бы усовершенствовал этот скрипт. Но это уже совсем другая история :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    
    function openImageModal(e) {
        var img = document.getElementById('img01');
        img.src = e.target.src;
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    
    var imgList = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-img'); //Ищем все изображения с классом modal-img
    for (var i in imgList) {
      imgList[i].addEventListener("click", openImageModal); // Добавляем всем изобраения слушателя клика
    }
    
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */

.modal-img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img id="myImg" src="http://placeimg.com/400/400/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
  <img id="myImg" src="http://placeimg.com/400/400/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
  <img id="myImg" src="http://placeimg.com/400/400/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
  
  
  
  
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img src="img/modern_modal.jpg" class="modal-content" id="img01">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

С использованием делегирования и без использования айди будет примерно так.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  
  if( e.target.classList.contains('modal-img') ) {
    imgSrc = e.target.dataset.src,
    modalImg = modal.querySelector('.modal-content');
    
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);
  } else if( e.target.classList.contains('close') ) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  
  if (event.target.closest('.modal')) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
.modal-pic{
  display: inline-block;
}

.modal-img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/400/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/500/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/600/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/700/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img src="img/modern_modal.jpg" class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD**: А вот так можно сделать модуль с небольшим АПИ: `.init()` — чтобы инициализировать и `.destroy()` чтобы убрать инициализацию.

```js
var myModal = Modal({
  img: '.modal-img',
  modal: '.modal',
  innerImg: '.modal-content'
});

myModal.init();

function Modal({
  img: img,
  modal: modal,
  innerImg: innerImg
}) {
  var imgEl = document.querySelectorAll(img),
      modalEl = document.querySelector(modal),
      innerImgEl = document.querySelector(innerImg);
  
  function listener(e) {
    if( e.target.matches(img) ) {
      var imgSrc = e.target.dataset.src;

      modalEl.classList.add('modal--visible');
      innerImgEl.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);
    } else if( e.target.matches('.close') ) {
      modalEl.classList.remove('modal--visible');
    }
  }

  function init() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', listener);
  }
  
  function destroy() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', listener);
  }

  return { init, destroy };
}
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
.modal-img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal.modal--visible {
  display: block;
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 450px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/400/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/410/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/420/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
    <img data-src="http://placeimg.com/430/400/any" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="img-responsive modal-img" alt="Responsive image">
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img src="img/modern_modal.jpg" class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!